# Problem when connecting to FTP server through android?

Tags: android, file-upload, ftp

I've an `UnknownHostException` when i used this method for uploading files from ddms:

```
try {
SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();

// Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
ftp.connect("ftp://*******", 21, "*****", "*****");

// Set binary mode.
ftp.bin();

// Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.
ftp.cwd("web");

// Upload some files.
ftp.stor(new File("data/data/com.android/file/contacts"));


// Quit from the FTP server.
ftp.disconnect();
}
catch (IOException e) {
// Jibble.
}
```

What is the problem for this method? Anyone clarify me.

Comment: You should include the logcat

Comment: @David Olsson : how to include the logcat. Please tell me the method.

Comment: Use adb logcat in the terminal. Or logcat view in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursory look at [SimpleFTP example](http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/) suggests that you need to use host name without `ftp://` prefix. Also make sure that you include INTERNET permission in manifest.

Comment: yes, you're right. if we declare the prefix in our ftp address. then, it'll no longer work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major problems with using FTP on the android emulator:

1. The emulator takes hold of a specific port on the host machine (between 5554 and 5584) to access the internet.

   See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html
2. FTP communicates on two ports.  The initial port (the one the emulator is using) and a secondary data communication port (usually defined by the FTP client and server).

   See http://www.troubleshootingnetworks.com/ftpinfo.html for information on how FTP works.

This means that the initial communication with the FTP server works the way it is intended, but once you are attempting to pass data to / from the server the emulator cannot communicate with the port the FTP server requests because your computer doesn't know what to do with the traffic on that port.  See the link above to get a better grasp on FTP communications.

If you want to test FTP on Android you will need to have a device with its own internet connection.

Comment: perfect ! ! ! that's why im not uploading my images with simulator. Now i understand. Thanks a lot for this answer!

Comment: is this answer still valid with the new Android emulator versions? The links mentioned are no longer existing. Kindly update.